# Change the url of a site scrolling

Tags: jquery, url, slider, anchor

sorry for my bad English.
I'm trying to create a site on a single scrollable page html, of course I'm using jquery.

The inspirations were:
http://activatedrinks.com
http://soulwire.co.uk

As you can see from the examples above, though the site is on a single page, but the url is changed dynamically according to the anchors.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    var windowScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
    if(windowScroll==100) window.location.hash='100';
    if(windowScroll==200) window.location.hash='200';
    if(windowScroll==300) window.location.hash='300';
});
```